# Add "waiting for review" line for comment flags

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, flag-history

Clearly, I have 2 flags pending, but it only says 1 flag is waiting for review.

[image]

One of them is a comment flag, but that's not specified.  A "waiting for review" section for comment flags would clear things up.

Comment: I think this is just because one of those pending flags is a *comment* flag, and those are counted separately.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Just about to edit that I just noticed that, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @DominatorX Yes, that too two years back... It would be great to have this feature-req or bug or whatever you name it.